# What is the most efficient way of querying for the most recent entries in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQL-flavoured database, with a simple table for logging events. Each event has a timestamp and is only updated from a single thread (hence we can trust that the entries in the table will always be in time order). The table may have many months of data. If I want to query the most recent entries, say the last day's worth, what is the best way to do this?

I could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp > [some time];
```

But this will have to check every event in the database. What I actually want to do in pseudo-code is:

```
get the rows at the end of the table back as far as where timestamp is greater than [some time]
```

Is this possible? Or necessary?

Comment: Add an `Order By timestamp desc` to get your events by their timestamp in most recent to most distant past order. You should always use an Order By clause if your data is structured by a particular order, to guarantee the results are arranged in a meaningful manner. Otherwise, your results come in whatever order the database feels like giving you for that point in time and space.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way is to use the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE timestamp > [some time];
```

(Comment:  that is your query.)

And to have an index on `timestamp`:

```
create index idx_events_timestamp on events(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the answer from @GordonLinoff. In my experience, there would have to be an extremely large amount of data for this to become slow - databases are optimised to handling this well when the column is indexed.

The thing here is that SQL doesn't guarantee the order in which rows are returned unless you use `ORDER BY`, which would be *far* slower.